# Replace all values of an Object from Integers to String if not null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs and currently trying to write a function in lambda, I have a query from a SQL database that gives me objects from fields with different schema. 
I need all those values to return as string if they are not null.

This works but it's just too much repetition. Do you know any better way, using foreach on Object.values.. or function etc..  I just can't get it right.

```
 a var Result = [];
 var item =  results.map(dataField) => {
     dataField.es_id  == null ? "" : dataField.es_id = dataField.es_id.toString();
     dataField.status  == null ? "" : dataField.status = dataField.status.toString();
     dataField.er_Act  == null ? "" : dataField.er_Act = dataField.er_Act.toString();

     Result.push(dataField);


});
callback(null, Result );
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dataField.es_id  == null ? "" : dataField.es_id = dataField.es_id.toString();` be `dataField.es_id  == null ? "" : dataField.es_id.toString();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all properties

```
a var Result = [];
var item = results.map(dataField) => {
  for (var property in dataField) {
      if (dataField.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          dataField[property] = dataField[property] === null ? "" : dataField[property].toString()
      }
  }

  Result.push(dataField);
});
callback(null, Result );
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty close to what I'm after, the problem is it turns (null ) to ( "" ), is there a way to keep null properties intact? ..as null

Comment: @adimona why not?) Just put ```null``` or ```dataField[property]``` instead of ```""```. Same result, null just shorter in this case.

Comment: @adimona, are you sure about the syntax in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to the property of `dataField` for the empty string to be properly put on the object, otherwise your `""` in

```
dataField.es_id  == null ? "" :
```

is just an unused expression.

To reduce code repetition, iterate over an array of properties:

```
const Result = [];
results.forEach((dataField) => {
  ['es_id', 'status', 'er_Act'].forEach((prop) => {
    dataField[prop] = dataField[prop] === null
    ? ''
    : dataField[prop].toString();
  });
  Result.push(dataField);
});
```

Or, if every property value on the object needs to be replaced, there's no need to hard-code the property names, and you can generate the result more functionally by iterating over the `Object.entries` of the input:

```
const Result = results.map((dataField) => (
  Object.entries(dataField).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    a[key] = val === null
    ? ''
    : val.toString();
    return a;
  }, {})
));
```